# Asynchronously wait for initialize device with timeout

Tags: c#, asynchronous, .net-7.0, avalonia

I have several devices to initialize, each device will be initialized by a single task.

Sometimes the device will report errors when it initializes failure and sometimes it will become unresponsive.

What I want to do is when all tasks receive a successful result then show the success UI to the user.

When all tasks are complete but with device(s) that initialized failure then show the details of which device(s) failed to initialize.

When the device initialization exceeds the timeout, show which devices have been initialized beyond the timeout.

How can I achieve this by `Task`? Currently I am using `.NET 7`.

Comment: Use `Task.WhenAll` inside a `try`/`catch` to await all the tasks, and then you can enumerate them one by one and check which is faulted, successful, cancelled, etc.

Comment: The cases successful and failure are pretty simple - just return a flag. To achieve timeout use [CancellationTokenSource.CancelAfter](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.cancelafter?view=net-7.0) that cancels using your timeout, forward that CancellationToken to your initialization and catch OperationCanceledException to indicate the timeout.

Comment: In .NET6 Task API got new method `Task.WaitAsync` with overloads, including TimeSpan as a parameter. It is better to use `Task.WhenAll(...).WaitAsync(timeout)` because if one or a few of the devices being initialized are not responding, your `Task.WhenAll` will wait them all. You can use cancellation too, but it is kinda natural approach now to use API designed for that. Just catch for `TimeoutException` in catch block.

Comment: Are the devices initialized only once during the lifetime of the process, or the initializations that failed might be retried?

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel But how can I achieve the timeout?

Comment: @SebastianSchumann This sounds interesting!

Comment: @Ryan Well, this way feels simpler.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Neither WPF nor Winform but Avalonia.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias The initializations will retry when the user press the retry button.

Comment: What is the desirable behavior in case the initialization of a device is timed-out, meaning that it is still potentially running, and the user presses the Retry button? Is it OK to invoke the initialization logic concurrently for the same device twice?

Comment: Are the initialization tasks cancelable? I.e. do they accept a `CancellationToken` as argument? If not, are they guaranteed to eventually complete either successfully or with failure? Or it is possible to get stuck and run forever?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias When the user clicks the retry button, it only reinitializes the device that is uninitialized. And the initialization cannot be cancelled until timeout or all device return it initialize result. The timeout is to prevent them get stuck and run forever.

Comment: Hmm, so **there is** a possibility that the initialization of a device will get stuck forever. How are you thinking to handle this case? By ignoring/forgetting the incomplete task, and starting a new task for the same device? Or you don't know how to handle it, and you are asking here for ideas? Your scenario is revealed to be much more complex than it is described in the question. There is no mention in the question about forever running tasks, or about retrying timed-out or failed tasks. Could you edit the question and include the missing details? Including some code would be nice too.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Other questions have been provided with solutions for me in other replies. My idea for what you mentioned is to find a way to kill the task if it times out.

Comment: I can see [one answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77154752/asynchronously-wait-for-initialize-device-with-timeout/77155009#77155009) by Ryan, which is based on assumptions that do not reflect your actual scenario. For example Ryan's `InitializedDevices` method takes a `CancellationToken`, while apparently your actual tasks do not (at least that's my understanding, correct me if I am wrong). If you want to get useful answers, you must put more effort on describing your actual scenario in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you should use a hybrid approach with Timeout-based and cancellation.

```
CancellationTokenSource tcs = new();
IEnumerable<Task> tasks = InitializedDevices(tcs.Token);
Task[] cancelled = Array.Empty<Task>();
bool wasCancellation = false;
TimeSpan timeout = ...;
try
{
   await Task.WhenAll(tasks).WaitAsync(timeout);
}
catch(TimeoutException)
{
   //due to nitty gritty things of handling exception
   //i would try to check status of tasks to cancel those still uncompleted
   //they might still consuming valuable resources
   if (tasks.Any(t => t.Status != TaskStatus.RanToCompletion))
   {
     cts.Cancel(); 
     wasCancellation = true;
   }
}
catch(Exception)
{
   //log some unexpected exception
}

if (wasCancellation)
{
  cancelled = tasks.Where(t => t.Status == TaskStatus.Cancelled).ToArray();
  //do whatever you want
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: Instead of `tasks.Any(t => t.Status != TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)` it is simpler `tasks.Any(t => !t.IsCompletedSuccessfully)`.

Comment: A better name for the `wasCancellation` might be `wasTimeout`. It is possible that in case of timeout, eventually none of the tasks will complete as canceled. They might all ignore the cancellation token, and complete successfully after the `timeout`.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, yeah, agree, this is about how intently tasks check for cancellation. it's just an implementation example, pure cancellation might look cleaner.